# developers.android.com Notepad Exercise 1, menu first function

Tags: android, android-listview

In `developer.android.com` website, I started doing [Notepad Exercise 1](http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/notepad-ex1.html). At step 9, point 2, you can read:

`Create a menu position constant at the top of the class:`

```
public static final int INSERT_ID = Menu.FIRST;
```

What is the purpose of this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It creates a constant, integer value for the first position in the menu. If you read further in the tutorial it will be used:

> This is going to handle our new "Add Note" menu item. When this is selected, the onOptionsItemSelected() method will be called with the item.getId() set to **INSERT_ID** (**the constant we used to identify the menu item**). We can detect this, and take the appropriate actions:

For an example of it being used:

```
menu.add(0, INSERT_ID, 0, R.string.menu_insert);
```

From the [Menu Documention](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html):

> public static final int FIRST First value for group and item identifier integers.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing mysterious here. As you can see here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#, Menu.FIRST in a constant, that's simply 1. In menu.add you define, that the first entry (Entry 1) of your list is an entry which will later call a method to add new notes.

So why not simply use 1 instead of Menu.FIRST? The thing is, although it is quite intuitive that the first entry has the number one, the Android-Guys at Google might also change it to start with 0 or any other number in a future release. So if you use Menu.FIRST your code will not break in that case, because they will change this constant at the same time.